# Write Python3/Pandas dataframe to JSON with orient=records but without the array when there is only one record

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm writing a very small Pandas dataframe to a JSON file. In fact, the Dataframe has only one row with two columns.

To build the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict({'date': '2020-10-05', 'ppm': 411.1}), orient='index').T
print(df)
```

prints

```py
         date    ppm
0  2020-10-05  411.1
```

The desired json output is as follows:

```json
{
  "date": "2020-10-05",
  "ppm": 411.1
}
```

but when writing the json with pandas, I can only print it as an array with one element, like so:

```
[
  {
    "date":"2020-10-05",
    "ppm":411.1
  }
]
```

I've currently hacked my code to convert the Dataframe to a dict, and then use the `json` module to write the file.

```py
import json
data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
data = data[0] # keep the only element
with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp, indent=2)
```

**Is there a native way with pandas' `.to_json()` to keep the only dictionary item if there is only one?**

I am currently using `.to_json()` like this, which *incorrectly* prints the array with one dictionary item.

```
df.to_json('data.json', orient='index', indent = 2)
```

---

Python 3.8.6
Pandas 1.1.3

Comment: `df.iloc[0].to_dict()`?

Comment: yes, would you like to post it as an answer? `df.iloc[0].to_json('test.json', indent = 2)` (I had to remove `orient=records`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export only one row, use `iloc`:

```
print (df.iloc[0].to_dict())

#{'date': '2020-10-05', 'ppm': 411.1}
```